# Gtkmm+Pango::layout

Tags: pango

How can i set different different text attributes to Pango::layout.

For example: I have a Text "WELCOME" and lets say "W" is bold,"E" is italic and "L" has red color and so on..
then if i render this text in cairo context using Pango::Layout, like

Glib::RefPtr layout = ...->create_pango_layout(); 
layout->set_text("WELCOME").
1. But I want individual character of this should be rendered with different Attributes.
2. I should be able to set line by line alignment also.

Please anyone help me to resole rendering issue with Pango::layout?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use layout->set_markup for that. http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html
2. Pango layout is designed to deal with whole paragraphs of text. So you would need a separate layout for each alignment.